# How do I properly extract a string from the clipboard

Tags: c#, string, uri, clipboard

So i'm trying to get the links from the clipboard, I manage to work it out just fine if I have one but I changed my method a bit because let's say I have more than 1 link saved in my clipboard.
I get this error

> Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string'

I dont see why, everything returns a string or a bool. What is causing this error and how do I resolve it?

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Text))
{
    string clipboardText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
    foreach (string link in clipboardText)
    {
        if (Uri.TryCreate(link, UriKind.Absolute, out var uri))
        {
            rtbLinks.AppendText(uri + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: 1] `clipboardText` is of type string, so `link`'s  type is char and not string. This is what is causing the error: *"Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string' "* 2] Why are you looping through a string? if you have more than one link saved to the clipboard, you must have some separator to split them right?

Comment: `clipboardText` is a string having an array of characters. Not an array of strings. Your foreach loop is not correct cause of this

Comment: If you first copy one link to the clipboard, and then copy a second link, the contents of the clipboard is overwritten with the second link. So there will only be one link in the clipboard at a time.

Answer (score 1):

A foreach-loop loops through a collection or an array.
In your case, you are using the string as the collection/array. That is somewhat possible; imagine a string as an array of type char.

You could use

```
foreach (char link in clipboardText)
{
    if (Uri.TryCreate(link, UriKind.Absolute, out var uri))
    {
        rtbLinks.AppendText(uri + "\n");
    }
}
```

That would only loop through each character of the string, though, and would not really solve your problem.

Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) for more information on the foreach-loop.

What you really need is an array of type string, where you store the links.
I imagine you have those strings split by a delimiter (like "|") in your clipboard, so you could modify your code like this:

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Text)) {
    string[] clipboardText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text).Split('|');
    foreach (string link in clipboardText) {
        if (Uri.TryCreate(link, UriKind.Absolute, out var uri)) {
            rtbLinks.AppendText(uri + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

If you have, e.g. `"https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com|https://stackoverflow.com"` in your clipboard, it will split the links into the array of string and you can work with those.

Without a delimiter, things might get a bit more tricky. You would then have to manually split those links into the string array first, and loop through that array afterwards.